# Responsive jQuery - variable inside an if else

Tags: jquery, variables, if-statement

I wish to change my variables based on the window width. If the window width is below 770px I wish for the variables to change their values.. shown below.

While this *is* working, it's causing quite a few errors.. is there a better/correct way to do this?

Thanks.

```
var window_width = $(window).width();
if (window_width < 770){
    var watch_shelf_height = 35;
    var listen_shelf_height = 45;
    var read_shelf_height = 55;
}else {
    var watch_shelf_height = 50;
    var listen_shelf_height = 55;
    var read_shelf_height = 65;
}
// my code
```

Comment: Declare your variables outside the if statement with a base value and then update them within the if statement (like you are already). That might help you out

Comment: What errors are you seeing?

Comment: It doesn't seem like that would cause any errors ?

Comment: I was getting 'watch_shelf_height' is already defined and some of my code was referencing the if, some the else.. @satpal's answer solved this. Syntax technicalities I'm sure..

Comment: Then you're doing something seriously wrong, as both parts of the if/else can't be executed, that would defeat the point entirely ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will do it this way. Declare your variables outside the if statement. Changes variables value base on certain condition.

```
var window_width = $(window).width();
var watch_shelf_height = 50;
var listen_shelf_height = 55;
var read_shelf_height = 65;

if (window_width < 770){
    watch_shelf_height = 35;
    listen_shelf_height = 45;
    read_shelf_height = 55;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. What is the reason for this working and mine not, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: Seems like it's exactly the same to me ?